# Which maintainability metric has the strongest empirical evidence?

Tags: empirical-research, metrics

There are lots of code metrics that claim to measure maintainability, e.g. CK and Li & Henry metric suits. However, it seems elusive to me to find a meta-study that compares different metrics to decide their current empirical status.

In contrast, here's a quite brilliant such study about *fault prediction*: https://romisatriawahono.net/lecture/rm/survey/software%20engineering/Software%20Fault%20Defect%20Prediction/Radjenovic%20-%20Software%20fault%20prediction%20metrics%20-%202013.pdf

I'm looking for something similar for maintainability/changeability prediction.

To be clear, there are multiple meta-studies on maintainability metrics, but they don't seem to compare their evidence, more like listing what's been researched about and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the study [Empirical evidence on the link between object-oriented measures and external quality attributes: a systematic literature review (PDF)](http://gmm.fsksm.utm.my/%7Emrazak/articles/Springer--Jabangwe_2014--Empirical_evidence_on_the_link_between_object-oriented_measures_and_external_quality_attributes.pdf) by Ronald Jabangwe, Juurgen Borstler, Darja Smite, Claes Wohlin, 2014. They selected 99 papers to review in total.

[image]

"Vote counting" here means to get a point (or two) for each study that shows a strong connection between the specific metric and maintainability.

### Description of important metrics

WMC = Weighted method for classes.

> Weighted methods for Class (WMC) was originally proposed by C&K as the sum of all the complexities of the methods in the class [3](http://www.virtualmachinery.com/sidebar3.htm).

LOC = Lines of code; todo: size of class, function, library, code-base?

RFC = Response for class

> This is the size of the Response set of a class. The Response set for a class is defined by C&K as 'a set of methods that can potentially be executed in response to a message received by an object of that class' [3](http://www.virtualmachinery.com/sidebar3.htm).

CBO = Coupling between objects

> Coupling between objects (CBO) is a count of the number of classes that are coupled to a particular class i.e. where the methods of one class call the methods or access the variables of the other [3](http://www.virtualmachinery.com/sidebar3.htm).

DIT = Depth of inheritance tree

> Depth of Inheritance Tree (DIT) is a count of the classes that a particular class inherits from [3](http://www.virtualmachinery.com/sidebar3.htm).

NOC = Number of children

> Number of Children (NOC) is defined by C&K the number of immediate subclasses of a class [3](http://www.virtualmachinery.com/sidebar3.htm).

### Quotes from the study

> There are insufficient numbers of studies on maintainability to draw conclusions. Nevertheless, Fig. 7 [picture above] shows that there is a potential link between maintainability, and measures that quantify complexity and cohesion properties.

> Results from our systematic review suggest that inheritance measures have a weak link with reliability and maintainability across studies, particularly the two inheritance measures DIT and NOC.

The study also notes that code metrics must be regarded in an organizational context:

> team structure and team strategy can vary across development settings, and studies show that such organizational characteristics have an impact on quality